# C++ while (true) vs while (!something)

Tags: c++, do-while

So let's say we have a bit of code in which we want the user to say something specific, but we want to give them infinite tries if they get it wrong. I would use a `do while` loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
  std::string input;
  std::cout<<"Enter yes or no: ";
  do {
    std::cin>>input;
    if (input == "yes") {
      break;
    } else if (input == "no") {
      break;
    } else {
      std::cout<<std::endl<<"Enter yes or no: ";
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

But, I have been told that it is bad practice to use `while (true);`, and, (in this case), I should instead use `while (input != "yes" && input != "no");`. Which one of them is correct?

`std::cout<<"Thanks!";`

Comment: Both one can works fine,but if we use `while (!something)` then we can easily get when the loop stops,if you use `while(true)` when the code become complex,it's difficult to find when the loop stops

Comment: Most "bad" practices are good sometimes, and "good" practices sometimes bad. I would probably collapse the conditions into one and move the prompt to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: It is not bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should test for input-failure (you forgot), and then whether you have to loop on. Thus, it should be:

```
while ((std::cin >> input) && input != "yes" && input != "no")
    std::cout << "\nEnter yes or no: ";
```

You shouldn't use `std::endl` when you don't need an explicit flush.

Or, better yet, encapsulate it in a re-usable function, and throw an exception on input-failure.